# https, a subdomain and an iframe: Any alternative to purchasing an additional SSL certificate?

Tags: iframe, https, ssl-certificate, mixed-content

I have a website `example.com` and an SSL certificate for this domain only. No subdomains except `www` are included. The site is based on Typo3.

On `example.com/map` is an iframe (note the subdomain):

```
<iframe src=„https://map.example.com“ width="400" height="300">
```

This doesn’t work with all browsers. Some browsers show an error (`SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN`) because the subdomain is not covered by the certificate.

The subdomain contains rather complex content which I wouldn’t know how to built in Typo3, that’s why I used an iframe.

## Question:

Is there any way to insert the contents of `map.example.com` into the page `example.com/map` without purchasing an additional SSL certificate for the subdomain?

Thanks
Pida

Comment: No - not unless you want to proxy it through a server for which you have a valid certificate. (Of course “buying” certificates is not really necessary any more these days in most cases - Let’s Encrypt provides certificates for free, provided you can install one of the clients on your server to obtain one.)

Answer (score 1):

I see the following solutions:

- Get a certificate for map.example.com

  - Buy one
  - Use an [ACME](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_Certificate_Management_Environment) client, for example [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org)
- Link: Instead of using an iFrame just link to the site map.example.com
- Set up a reverse proxy
- Server side include: Write an extension for the website `example.com/map` which includes the content from `map.example.com`
- Rebuild the solution as TYPO3 extension

It is difficult to say which one fits best for you.

A server side include may be easy in some cases, but in most cases it requires a lot of search an replace for the content which is going to be pasted. It also requires to include asset files (images, javascript, css) either in the TYPO3 template or dynamically by parsing the whole include content.

A reverse proxy is easy to set up in case you have the required software components already installed an the required knowledge. Otherwise it requires some reading and some hours to set up.